# How to change @SerializedName, from GSON, of an attribute in a extended class

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations, gson

I have a class like this:

```
class A {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("a_id")
    private String id;
}
```

Now I want to create class B that extends A, but, in B, I want to change the SerializedName of id to "b_id". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't that break the class contract? A class B object would be an instance of class B (due to inheritance) but would not offer the id field that class A object offer...

Comment: I understand your idea, but I dont think so, because annotations changes caracteristics of the attribute, like getters and setters, so theorically I can do this in a  child class.

Comment: For example, Hibernate allow me  [Hibernate inheritance](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2011/12/hibernate-inheritance-table-per-concrete-class-annotation-xml-mapping.html)  See "Hibernate Inheritance: Annotation Mapping", where @Inheritance makes the trick. I just want to know if GSON has the same feature.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible out of the box. You'll need to write a custom type adapter. See the [Custom Serialization and Deserialization](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization) section of the Gson user's guide.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did: I extended the class A, added a new parameter with the new serializer, and then  the overridden getter returns the new parameter:

```
class B extends A {

    @SerializedName("b_id")
    private String newId;

    @Override
    public @NotNull String getId() {
        return newId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

apply @SerializedName("b_id") to the setter in B

class B {
    private String id;

```
@SerializedName("b_id")
private void setId(String id);
```

}

Comment: this doesn't work